# scanBasePackages on SpringBootApplication breaks endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am using an external dependency in my SpringBootApplication.

The main class is defined as

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.companyA.app"})
    public class ApidemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ApidemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

The client class is defined as

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "companyA")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyClient {
      @Autowired
      @ConstructorBinding
      public MyClient(ApiClient apiClient){
             this.apiClient = apiClient);
      }
}
```

When I use the scanBasePackages annotation, all my existing endpoints stop working, giving a 404 not found

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-02-02T00:33:43.210+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/endpoint1"
}
```

If I do not use the scanBasePackages annotation, the compile fails with the error:

```
MyClient is annotated with @ConstructorBinding but it is defined as a regular bean which caused dependency injection to fail.

Action:

Update your configuration so that MyClient is defined via @ConfigurationPropertiesScan or @EnableConfigurationProperties.
```

Why is scanBasePackages breaking all my endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, If it helps other people in the future.

Make sure you are also scanning the packages that contain your endpoints.

For example, if you have packages `com.companyA.lib` and `com.companyA.app`  where `lib` contains some shared code and `app` has your endpoints.

Instead of scanning only classes in `lib`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.companyA.lib"})
```

Make sure you are scanning both packages:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.companyA.lib", "com.companyA.app"})
```

this way SpringBoot will scan the dependencies in both packages.